# How do I get my program to exit if the user inputs 'N'?

Tags: java

How do I get my program to exit if the user inputs 'N'?

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Would you like to buy and dairy products? Y/N ");
String answer = scan.nextLine();

switch (answer)
{
case "Y":
case "y":
    System.out.println("\nHere are our list of dairy products:-");
    break;
case "N":
case "n"://exit from program;
    System.out.println("You don't want any dairy items");
    break;
default :
    System.out.println("Invalid choice, please select Yes/No bu entering the characters 'Y'/'N'");
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming this is within the main method, you could just use a `return;` statement, which ends the method and consequently the program.

Otherwise `System.exit()` will work.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly better way of doing...what your doing:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Would you like to buy any dairy products? Y/N ");
String answer = "";

while (!answer.equals("y") && !answer.equals("n")) {
    answer = scan.nextLine().toLowerCase();

    switch (answer) {
        case "y":
            System.out.println("\nHere are our list of dairy products:-");
            break;
        case "n"://exit from program;
            System.out.println("You don't want any dairy items");
            System.exit(0); // program terminates if N or n was supplied.
            break;
        default :
            System.out.println("Invalid choice, please select Yes/No by entering the characters Y or N");
            break;
    }
}
// Code continues here if Y or y was supplied.
```